# Look up table for 3D to 2D EPSG CRS

Tags: python, coordinate-system, 3d, epsg

I would like to write a function (in Python) that receives a 3D EPSG CRS and returns the horizontal EPSG CRS equivalent.
Eg. Receiving 7415 (Amersfoort / RD New + NAP height) -> Returning  28992 (Amersfoort)

Is there an API/library where I could find this information for all EPSG codes? I could not find something like this in pyproj.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could possibly use the official EPSG registry swagger API ~ https://apps.epsg.org/api/swagger/ui/index

Note that EPSG codes don't just refer to CRS, but rather all components of a CRS, plus transformations between CRS.